# How to automatically login to the website by Chrome with Applescript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, applescript

I want to use Google Chrome for automatic login to the website (https://account.nicovideo.jp/login).

I know how to use Applescript with Safari, but I don't know how should I script for Chrome.

This is my Applescript for Safari's automatic login. How could I do the same thing with Chrome?

---

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    if URL of document 1 starts with "https://account.nicovideo.jp/login" or URL of document 1 starts with "https://secure.nicoga.jp/" then
        do JavaScript "document.forms[0].mail_tel.value='example@email.com'" in document 1
        do JavaScript "document.forms[0].password.value='password in here'" in document 1
        do JavaScript "document.forms[0].submit()" in document 1
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

You execute the javascript, and the object is attached to the tab of the window. So:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    tell window 1
        tell active tab
            if (its URL) starts with "https://account.nicovideo.jp/login" or (its URL) starts with "https://secure.nicoga.jp/" then
                execute javascript "document.forms[0].mail_tel.value='example@email.com'"
                execute javascript "document.forms[0].password.value='password in here'"
                execute javascript "document.forms[0].submit()"
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```